# Php code both compatible with 7 and 5.4, conditional interperting, how?

Tags: php

for example:

```
private function t() : array
{
```

this works with 7 but wont with 5.4. I want something like IFDEF in Delphi. So,

```
private function t() IFPHPIS7 { : array }
{
```

or something like that. Is there anything like that?

Comment: There is no such thing in php.

Comment: You could write/find a preprocessor for PHP; but PHP doesn't have that built in.

Answer (score 2):

i think this can't be happen but vise versa will run  in php7 .

syntax changes from version to another, the later version works fine with the earlier if syntax didn't deprecated .